# Get every string of static block identifier Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module, static-block, menu, customize

I have to modify mega menu extension in Magento 1.9. Currently, its showing static block at bottom of category.

[image: image_bottom]
I want to separate static block identifier name based on some symbol like `_` in my custom block code function.

In one of the block folder file below code is written.

```
const CUSTOM_BLOCK_TEMPLATE = "wp_custom_menu_%d";
 $blockId = sprintf(self::CUSTOM_BLOCK_TEMPLATE, $id); 
 $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array(array('like' => $blockId . '_w%'), array('eq' => $blockId)))
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
        $blockId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getIdentifier();
```

Static block identifier is suggested to be named as `wp_custom_menu_HereCatID`

What i want is to achieve the  name of static block identifer as something like this `wp_custom_menu_HereCatId_Right` for Right and  `wp_custom_menu_HereCatId_Bottom` for Bottom position

I can use explode, but i want to learn in Magento way as done above.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom field to the category where admin can choose bottom or side [here](https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/) you find how to do it . 
after that you enter to the megamenu plugin and customize the code : if field value = side you add a css class .sideblock to the static block else you add the class  .bottomblock 
all the rest is to create the css of the 2 classes